# MySQL 5.1.65 | Select Where Not Finding Something I know Is There

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm trying to use this disgusting version of MySQL (5.1.65)  where its requiring EVERYTHING to be in quotes, and is so strict about everything. I'm trying to look for duplicate entries so I'm trying to make a script that if it returns a value of what the user submitted, then obviously we have a duplicate. Well thats working on MY server, not this one.

This is what I'm trying to execute. This goes through fine without error,

```
SELECT * FROM `keylist` WHERE 'key' = '7489asdf32749asdf8237492asdf49837249'
```

The issue is that 7489asdf32749asdf8237492asdf49837249 IS in the database as a varchar...Its exactly the same. But the weird thing is that if I do

```
SELECT * FROM `keylist` WHERE key = '7489asdf32749asdf8237492asdf49837249'
```

That does not work while if I did that for selecting my ID it works.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but this stupid MySQL version sure isn't helping.

Overall, my issue is that I'm trying to look for a duplicate, so I do a WHERE key = statement, and a key that IS in there, returns nothing when I KNOW  its in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html

Your first version works becomes the backtics - `` `  ` `` force interpretation to the actual column name.

Comment: Yes it is backticks.  Updated further.

Comment: woohoo! Thank you...Was tearing my hair out, so much in fact I gave up for the night and went to bed :P

Comment: Yeah...although... on further examination (and with prompting from mu who is very sharp) I've realized that although you used backtics around keylist, you show using single quotes around key.  Is it possible you actually used backtics around key in the actual code/console, etc?